# Select multiple images with MediaPlugin (Cross-platform)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I need to implement the possibility to pick multiple images and load them in my app, after some researches I camer across this Package called MediaPlugin and I noticed that it has a method called PickPhotosAsync() that allows users to pick multiple images from the gallery.
So I set everything up in the iOs and Android as it's said in the page on GitHub and copy & pasted the code of the MainPage.
By the time I'm writing this I tried other solutions but all of them allow me just to pick a single image and I can't figure out why it doesn't work as it's expected to.
Here's some C# code (even though it's the same of the sample given by James Montamagno)

```
files.Clear();
if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
{
    await DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
    return;
}

var picked = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotosAsync();

if (picked == null)
    return;
foreach (var file in picked)
    files.Add(file);
```

And here's the Xaml page

```
<StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="pickPhoto" Text="Carica Foto" />
    <Button x:Name="takePhoto" Text="Scatta Foto" />
    <Label x:Name="label" />
</StackLayout>
```

Comment: Check  https://xamgirl.com/select-multiple-images-from-gallery-in-xamarin-forms/.

Answer (score 0):

I will not post the entire code (since it is too much) but [here is a complete tutorial](http://www.xamboy.com/2019/03/12/select-multiple-images-and-videos-in-xamarin-forms/) on how to achieve that.

It uses a Native iOS library, and the complete implementation on Android.

Comment: I need to pass as a parameter the interface MultiMediaPickerService but I can't  pass the instance of that